# sql server-using group by clause i want all values both null and not null values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I wrote a query in sql server like below...

```
SELECT 
      [AC_NO],part_no,  
      SUM(CASE WHEN sex='M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as male , 
SUM(CASE when sex='F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as female,
SUM(CASE when sex='o' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as other,
SUM(CASE WHEN sex='M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as male
 FROM [ALL_ERMS_S1_S2_2014].[dbo].[ALL_MR_ERMS] where ORG_LIST_NO=2 and ac_no=91 and  STATUSTYPE='N'
group by ac_no,part_no
order by ac_no,part_no



**ac_no PART_NO male    female  other   total**

    91    2  1    0   0   1

    91    3   1   1   0   2

    91    4   1   1   0   2

    91    7   1   1   0   2

    91    8   4   2   0   6
```

I got result like below ....

In the Part_no col you can mark 1,5,6 is missing b in that part all values are 0. I want like below..

```
        ac_no   PART_NO  male   female  other     total

           91      1      0    0       0         0

           91      2      1    0       0         1

           91      3      1    1       0         2

           91      4      1    1       0         2

           91      5      0    0       0         0

           91      6      0    0       0        0

           91      7      1    1       0        2

           91      8      4    2       0        6
```

Please help me ....
How can I get this result....

Comment: Have you a list off all parts?

Comment: Yes, how are we/SQL meant to know which part numbers are missing? Are we to assume that part numbers are consecutively numbered, start at 1, and that the highest part number *is* present in your result? Or do we obtain them from elsewhere?

Comment: Check the STATUSTYPE='N'of Part_No 1,5,6